# How to unpivot and get a sum for each month + total?

Tags: sql, sql-server

## - Edited -

I have some employee data in my table with **sal** (salary) per **id**, **name**, **head** and **month** -

```
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| id | name | head  | month | sal  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | basic | jan   | 1000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | jan   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | basic | feb   | 1000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | feb   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | basic | mar   | 1000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | mar   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | basic | apr   | 1000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | apr   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | basic | may   | 1000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | may   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | basic | june  | 1000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | june  | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | basic | july  | 1000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | july  | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | basic | aug   | 1000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | aug   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | basic | sep   | 1000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | sep   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | basic | oct   | 1000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | oct   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | basic | nov   | 1000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | nov   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | basic | dec   | 1000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | dec   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
|    |      |       |       |      |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | basic | mar   | 2000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | hra   | mar   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | basic | apr   | 2000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | hra   | apr   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | basic | may   | 2000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | hra   | may   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | basic | june  | 2000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | hra   | june  | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | basic | july  | 2000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | hra   | july  | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | basic | aug   | 2000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | hra   | aug   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | basic | sep   | 2000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | hra   | sep   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | basic | oct   | 2000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | hra   | oct   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | basic | nov   | 2000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | hra   | nov   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | basic | dec   | 2000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2  | B    | hra   | dec   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
|    |      |       |       |      |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | basic | jan   | 5000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | hra   | jan   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | basic | feb   | 5000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | hra   | feb   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | basic | mar   | 5000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | hra   | mar   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | basic | apr   | 5000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | hra   | apr   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | basic | may   | 5000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | hra   | may   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | basic | june  | 5000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | hra   | june  | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | basic | july  | 5000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | hra   | july  | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | basic | aug   | 5000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | hra   | aug   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | basic | sep   | 5000 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
| 3  | C    | hra   | sep   | 500  |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+
```

I'm achieving to get a row per **id**,**name** and **head**,
with a sum column of **sal** for each month + the total for all columns.
(P.s. months display starts with April)

```
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| id | name | head  | apr  | may  | jun  | jul  | aug  | sep  | oct  | nov  | dec  | jan  | feb  | mar  | total |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 1  | A    | basic | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 12000 |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 6000  |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 2  | B    | basic | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 0    | 0    | 2000 | 24000 |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 2  | B    | hra   | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 0    | 0    | 500  | 6000  |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 3  | C    | basic | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 | 0    | 0    | 0    | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 | 60000 |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 3  | C    | hra   | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 0    | 0    | 0    | 500  | 500  | 500  | 6000  |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

Comment: That's not a question, it's not even remotely acceptably formatted, and we're not a free code-writing service.

Comment: @RaviKumar Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Some of your total calculations seems to be wrong (compare it to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
select      id,name,head
           ,apr,may,june,july,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec,jan,feb,mar
           ,apr+may+june+july+aug+sep+oct+nov+dec+jan+feb+mar   as total

from       (select      id
                       ,name
                       ,head

                       ,coalesce (apr  ,0)    as apr
                       ,coalesce (may  ,0)    as may
                       ,coalesce (june ,0)    as june
                       ,coalesce (july ,0)    as july
                       ,coalesce (aug  ,0)    as aug
                       ,coalesce (sep  ,0)    as sep
                       ,coalesce (oct  ,0)    as oct
                       ,coalesce (nov  ,0)    as nov
                       ,coalesce (dec  ,0)    as dec
                       ,coalesce (jan  ,0)    as jan
                       ,coalesce (feb  ,0)    as feb
                       ,coalesce (mar  ,0)    as mar

            from        mytable pivot (sum(sal) for month in
                            (apr,may,june,july,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec,jan,feb,mar)) p      
            ) p
```

---

```
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| id | name | head  | apr  | may  | jun  | jul  | aug  | sep  | oct  | nov  | dec  | jan  | feb  | mar  | total |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 1  | A    | basic | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 12000 |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 1  | A    | hra   | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 6000  |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 2  | B    | basic | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 0    | 0    | 2000 | 20000 |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 2  | B    | hra   | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 0    | 0    | 500  | 5000  |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 3  | C    | basic | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 | 0    | 0    | 0    | 5000 | 5000 | 5000 | 45000 |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 3  | C    | hra   | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 500  | 0    | 0    | 0    | 500  | 500  | 500  | 4500  |
+----+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

Comment: When you answer questions like these you make it seem like it's OK to use SO as a code-writing service.

Comment: @Biffen,this question didn't strike me as code-writing service request. It seemed more like a language barrier. It didn't contain images. It contained a good text sample including desired results (although with some errors).

Comment: Ravi are you there?